# Caffe installation

Tags: cuda, nvidia, caffe

I'm installing Caffe.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I tried to install cuda. On Caffe site is written that I need to install the library and the latest standalone driver separately.

I downloaded driver from [there](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us). I tried every product type, but I get the same error:

```
You do not appear to have an NVIDIA GPU supported by the 346.46 
NVIDIA Linux graphics driver installed in this system. For further 
details, please see the appendix SUPPORTED NVIDIA GRAPHICS CHIPS in 
the README available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

And then

```
You appear to be running an X server; please exit X before            
installing.  For further details, please see the section INSTALLING   
THE NVIDIA DRIVER in the README available on the Linux driver         
download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

And

```
Installation has failed.  Please see the file
'/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for details.  You may find            
suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README available   
on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

I successfuly installed cuda and cuDNN.

Then I downloaded Caffe from [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe).

Then I tried to compile and after I did `make all` and `make test`,
I did `make runtest` and get this error:

```
Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (38 vs. 0)  no CUDA-capable device is detected
```

Also I found that I need to verify that I have a CUDA-Capable GPU.
This command: `lspci | grep -i nvidia` doesn't return anything. `update-pciids` doesn't help neither, though it returns `Downloaded daily snapshot dated`.

Can anyone help me install Caffe and everything correctly?

Comment: Do you actually have a CUDA compatible GPU?

Comment: @talonmies I don't know, but [there](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#verify-you-have-cuda-enabled-system) is written that I need to do command `lspci | grep -i nvidia`. But it doesn't return anything, as I wrote. And `update-pciids` doesn't help.

Comment: So what is your question? "Can I use caffe without a CUDA GPU?" or "How can I tell if I have  CUDA GPU?", or what?

Comment: @talonmies I want to know if I have a CUDA-Capable GPU, and if not, what I can do about it, because I really need Caffe.

Comment: @Александра Seems you don't have a CUDA-enabled GPU. You may have no Nvidia graphics card/chip in your system, or at least it isn't supported.
What you can do is buying one and installing it in your system, if it is a desktop computer with enough place in the case and a good enough power supply. If it's a laptop, then there is 99% probability you can't add or change hardware. This goes out of the stackoverflow range, I think.
You may try the answer suggestion to force CPU only while building the software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your system apparently does not have a CUDA compatible GPU. Depending on what type of system you are using (most likely a desktop or server with appropriate free PCI-e slot(s), case space, and sufficient power supply capacity), it *might* be possible to purchase and install such a GPU.

Still you can get started with Caffe, by not using GPU by uncommenting `CPU_ONLY` flag in Makefile.config

Answer (score 0):

> Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (38 vs. 0)  no CUDA-capable device
>   is detected

Assuming you have a GPU card, the above error can come if NVDIA Driver is not installed / used by the system.

Please check this link - https://askubuntu.com/questions/670485/how-to-inspect-the-currently-used-nvidia-driver-version-and-switch-it-to-another

Check the latest driver version from Nvidia site for your card. Then add the relevant repository and install via that. Better to restart

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install nvidia-3xx
>
> sudo modeporbe nvidia (also ran this before restart)

Check via nvidia-smi command

alex@alex-Lenovo-G400s-Touch:~$ nvidia-smi
Tue Feb 28 15:10:50 2017

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.39                 Driver Version: 375.39                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 720M     Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    271MiB /  1985MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                  Not Supported                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Install samples and test via deviceQuery after making the samples --> http://xcat-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/gpu/nvidia/verify_cuda_install.html

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 720M"
...

After that Reconfigure Caffe and do a clean make
Below are the CMake settings for reference and the CMake file http://pastebin.com/qAd40uvh

[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Probably you don't have CUDA compatible card. Also, you may have it, but you are not using it. i.e. If you have a NVidia card and Integrated graphics, you should make sure your monitor has plugged in your NVidia Card output interface.

You should make sure that your graphics card indeed support CUDA at http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/cuda/supported-gpus?field_gpu_type_value=All. Find your graphics card in this list, until you find your card.

p.s. To find your graphics card info, you can run `lspci | grep VGA` in the shell.